# shopware 6, custom block slider and text

Tags: shopware6

I would like to create a custom block with an image slider and text for each slide. Now i've created one following online [documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-block)

```
import './component';
import './preview';

Shopware.Service('cmsService').registerCmsBlock({
    name: 'multicolumn-carousel',
    category: 'text-image',
    label: 'Multicolumn carousel',
    component: 'sw-cms-block-multicolumn-carousel',
    previewComponent: 'sw-cms-preview-multicolumn-carousel',
    defaultConfig: {
        marginBottom: '20px',
        marginTop: '20px',
        marginLeft: '20px',
        marginRight: '20px',
        sizingMode: 'boxed'
    },
    slots: {
        topone: 'image',
        botone: 'text',
        toptwo: 'image',
        bottwo: 'text',
        topthree: 'image',
        botthree: 'text',
        topfour: 'image',
        botfour: 'text'
    }
});
```

in this case i can only render 4 slides, how can i dinamically add as much slots as i want in order to loop them when i need to render the slider?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you need a dedicated slot per slide? Either you have a set number of slides, then you can have dedicated slots, or you allow an unlimited number of slides, then you just have a single slot that contains all items.

Just have a look at the [default image gallery implementation](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/d1d52735823eecf999cfeffd538731c7ae4dcc3b/src/Administration/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/blocks/image/image-gallery/index.js#L18). If the existing element type `image-gallery` doesn't meet your requirements, you'll have to register your own element. See the documentation on [adding custom elements](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/content/cms/add-cms-element) for use in blocks.